# Load Data into Datagridview Combobox

Tags: c#, sql

I have 2 field First "Name" and second "NIC" the "Name" Is text field and "NIC" Is combobox field.

My query is i want to load data which is already save into SQL and i want to load it again on my grid how i can do that LIKE the below is my sql result

| name | nic |
| --- | --- |
| FT Muhammad Ejaz | 32-3242-23532 |
| DMB Omer | 654564 |
| Yasir Wajid | 35 |
| HO Zeeshan Hussain | 654987987 |
| SC Ameen Ghulam Rasool | 64654 |
| BBBT Hafiz Adil | 5464 |
| DHA Ghayas | 6456 |
| SC Jameel Maseeh | 6456 |
| GBB Abdullah Khairat Ali | 65456465 |
| DHA Hamid Manzoor | 762837 |

I am new in C# if Any Missing Please ignore

Here is my Code for  These two field in C#

```
  string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyCONN"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
                string sqlquery = "select top 5 Name,nic from salesman order by nic asc";
                sqlconn.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
                SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sdr.Fill(dt);            
                dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Name";           
                sqlconn.Close();
```

Regards,

Comment: Check the following [code sample](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/q-a-questions/tree/master/DataGridViewCombo), first column is text, second column is a DataGridViewComboBox. There is a [screenshot](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/q-a-questions/blob/master/DataGridViewCombo/assets/figure1.png) showing what it looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = yourData
```

But I would suggest using Entity Framework when working with databases.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

Comment: it not loading data into grid i have tried this one